# Defining a duplicate row by the first 20 characters of a cell

Tags: google-apps-script

I am running a basic de-duplication script for a Google spreadsheet and have hit  roadblock. I want to base whether or not a row is a duplicate on only the first 20 characters in the columns I have defined, not the entire contents of the column.

I ran multiple searches and haven't found anything even close. I keep coming up with ways to remove the first X characters, but that doesn't do me any good.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```html
function removeDuplicates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = new Array();
  for(i in data){
    var row = data[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for(j in newData){
      if(row[0] == newData[j][0] && row[4] == newData[j][4]){
  duplicate = true;
}
    }
    if(!duplicate){
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

Comment: The current code doesn't address the first 20 characters. That's what I'm having trouble with. The script here works, but uses the entire contents of each cell to determine if rows are duplicates. I need to be able to limit that to only the first 20 characters of the cell as the contents of each cell are being appended with a unique URL.

Comment: Here is the spreadsheet I am using: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dddgoZ8yBmgg5llYnbPJFdmae_07YiyMp256cYqarmg/edit?usp=sharing

The ultimate goal is to determine duplicate rows based only on the first 20 characters of the cells in column B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were nearly there, If you could compare first 20 characters of column B of your spreadsheet with saved array, you can find duplicates.

> **substring()** is the function you need to use

Read more: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

```
function removeDuplicates() 
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = new Array();
  for(var i in data)
  {
    var row = data[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for(var j in newData)
    {
    //row[1]=> column B value 
      if(row[1].substring(0,20) == newData[j][1].substring(0,20)){
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    if(!duplicate){
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: @RichardHostler you can mark this is as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you want an array with the first 20 characters of all the values in the specified column

```
var columnNumber = 2
var values = data.map(function(el){ 
    return /^.{0,20}/.exec(el[columnNumber + 1]).toString() 
})
```

Then, you want to go through the array and see if there is a duplicate

```
for (var row = 1; row < values.length; row++){
    var dupIndex = values.indexOf(values[row],row + 1)
    if (~dupIndex)
    {
        Browser.msgBox("Row " + (row + 1) + " and Row " + (dupIndex + 1) + " are identical")
        // Act on the duplicate rows here
    }
}
```

I hope this at least gives a good starting point, good luck!